# How do I tell an activity to finish?

Tags: android

I have two `Activity` subclasses. One is my `MainActivity`, the other is a splash screen called `SplashActivity`. Here is what I want to happen:

1. Open my app
2. App `MainActivity` starts up
3. The `MainActivity` starts the `SplashActivity` with `startActivity()` method.
4. The main activity starts doing some setup/loading that takes a while.
5. The loading/setup work finishes
6. Stop the `SplashActivity` and go back to the `MainActivity`.

I launch the `SplashActivity` with this code in `MainActivity.onCreate()`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class));
```

How can I tell the `SplashActivity` to pop off the screen and go back to the `MainActivity` from `MainActivity` itself?

EDIT: Note that I did some research on this before asking. The only solution I've found involved doing something from *within* `SplashActivity` itself, but the `SplashActivity` doesn't really control itself in the model I'm thinking about. The `MainActivity` is controlling the splash from outside. If this isn't how it should work, I'm open to a new approach/design as well.

Comment: you need to use `AsyncTask` to achieve your needs, like this: `onPreExecte(){ //startSplashScreenActivity} doInBackground(){//Your Work Here} onPostExecute(){// finish SplashScreenActivity}`

Comment: you mean to say that you are doing the controlling from your mainActivity itself , splashActivity is just an activity to show in foreground ?

Comment: That's correct. There is no business logic in `SplashActivity`. The `MainActivity` needs to control the lifecycle of `SplashActivity`.

Comment: *The MainActivity needs to control the lifecycle of SplashActivity* **it is not possible on android** you have to think like there could be only one(top) activity working ... keep in mind that there is an option "Don't keep activities"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing the same is instead of using a separate activity for the splash screen, you can add a view in XML for splash screen which cover the entire screen of MainActivity and then hide it (by setting its visibility to GONE) whenever your setup/loading finishes.

Comment: seriously, it is better solution than EventBus, BroadcastReceiver and singleTask ...

Comment: I think so, 'cause using an activity just for few seconds is not worth. And for using BroadcastReceiver, EventBus or any other complex methods, one has to take care for their listeners and manage lifecycle events accordingly. And while using XML for the splash screen, all you've to do is make its view VISIBLE or GONE. Also, it can be done in few lines of code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Call the `finish()` function on the **SplashActivity** after your work is done on the **MainActivity**.

Comment: I don't have an instance variable for `SplashActivity`. How  can I call `finish()` on it from outside?

Comment: You don't need an instance of **SplashActivity** just call `finish()` function It should work. To close any activity we call `finish();` If you want to close **SplashActivity** then you should call `finish()` on **SplashActivity** and it will close the activity and go back to **MainActivity**.

Comment: What I mean is, that `SplashActivity` has no user controls. No way of knowing when it should go away. `MainActivity` is the only one that knows when the `SplashActivity` should be finished.

Answer (score 0):

[Activity#finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())

That is certainly the call that you require when you are done with your Activity and it needs closing.

There are two straight forward answers that I can think of.

First, from your question "The loading/setup work finishes", you can definitely invoke `finish()` at this point in `SplashActivity`.

Second, hold an instance of `SplashActivity` in the parent `MainActivity` and let the two activities communicate with each other. As in, when loading/setup finishes, let the `MainActivity` know using a listener and at the time the `MainActivity` can finish the `SplashActivity`. However, be careful with holding and not leaking the instance of `SplashActivity`.

On a different note though, and I'm asking this because your requirement and implementation is not very clear to me, pls ask yourself if you **really** need the `SplashActivity`.

If you require a trivial loading UI, then, can you not do it within the `MainActivity`.

If you require a non-trivial loading UI, how about using a Fragment?